# Render menu block in twig template

Tags: theming, 8, blocks

- In `page--front.html.twig` I load a nested twig file `{% include
  "header.twig" {} %}`
- In `header.twig` I want to render my menu block

I tried the following but no result:

- In `my_theme.theme` I added:

```php
function crm_theme_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
  $block = \Drupal\block\Entity\Block::load('crmnavigation');
  $variables['block_output'] = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()
    ->getViewBuilder('block')
    ->view($block);
}
```

- In `header.twig` I added `{{ my_navigation }}` but it doesn't show the menu block?

Comment: if you define **$variables['block_output'] = xxx** in preprocess page, in twig template you need add {{ block_output }}. Variable **block_output** is array render of menu not **my_navigation**. So funny :D

Comment: thanks. In `header.twig` I added now `{{ block_output }}`, but nothing shows up?

Comment: Are you sure about block id **crmnavigation**?

Comment: If I go to admin/structure/block > (currently the menu block is Disabled) > click on Configure > Machine name: crmnavigation

Comment: @Jonh any solution? Do you know whats going wrong? Thanks

Comment: You need debug it. You can try use function kint($block) after load block. And try with different block_id. It you have right block. It'll rendered.

Comment: Why can't you just create a region to hold navigation, and place the block in there in the block layout?

Answer (score 4):

The easiest solution is to make use of twig tweaks module, Install twig tweak

```
drush -y en twig_tweak, 
drush cr,
```

now you can place navigation anywhere. In your case inside header.twig file place

```
{{ drupal_block('crmnavigation') }}
```

You can also render entities, views and many other things. well explained here http://www.wdtutorials.com/drupal/theming/drupal-8-tutorial-43-twig-tweak-module-article-video#.WCPOxeErIyk

Comment: As of version 1.5 you can use drupal_menu() function.

Answer (score 1):

There is a module that lets you do this called [Simplify Menu](https://www.drupal.org/project/simplify_menu).

In your Twig template, you make the call for the menu you want to fetch, and then wrap it in markup like so:

```
// Get menu items
{% set items = simplify_menu('main_navigation') %}

// Iterate menu tree
<nav class="navigation__items">
  {% for menu_item in items.menu_tree %}
    <li class="navigation__item">
      <a href="{{ menu_item.url }}">{{ menu_item.text }}</a>
    </li>
  {% endfor %}
</nav>
```

Although, my question still remains..

> Why can't you just create a region to hold navigation, and place the block in there in the block layout?

Comment: For multi-level menu items, how would you do with this?